# How angular 2.0 supports responsive design

Tags: angular, responsive-design

Does angular 2.0 helps responsive design with the help of bootstrap component or by itself does it have any inbuilt component to help. I am learning angular 2.0 answer this can help. Kindly share some other useful blogs for understanding angular 2.0 architechture

Comment: Angular2 does not have any built-in css framework for responsive design but it is just awesome to use any framework like bootstrap or material design.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular team have published a library: [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) to help with flex based responsive layouts.